# How to schedule jobs in to client systems using python?

Tags: python

i have 4 systems , where in one i am using as a master and the rest 3 as slaves. I want to execute a set of functions in client systems and fetch back the result, to achieve this i had previously used Parallel Python , unfortunately as soon as job_server is created in it , it internally executes the given function using all systems.  I want to individually assign particular function to be executed on an individual client machine , i have no idea on how to proceed with coding . Is there any framework in python, which allows users to do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is the `multiprocessing` module: http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html
You can find examples there that do exactly what you want (see [Remote Managers](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html#using-a-remote-manager)).

As a  side notice: I soon stumbled upon limitations in the `multiprocessing` module and now use [PyRo](http://www.xs4all.nl/~irmen/pyro3/) as middleware. It's very simple and powerful but requires a bit more work to set up a basic framework.

Answer (score 1):

There was a talk at a Pycon in the past few years about a tool that managed remote processes via ssh, which sounded really cool and I meant to check out. I've forgotten what the tool was, but you might find it by looking at the Pycon talks for the past few years.

The [Python Parallel Processing wiki page](http://wiki.python.org/moin/ParallelProcessing) has a big list of tools that might help you.

Answer (score 1):

I don't quite understand what you have now and what you're trying to do. [Pyro](http://www.xs4all.nl/~irmen/pyro3/) is easy to use, pretty fast and well documented for letting multiple python processes (on multiple systems) interact with each other. Take a look at that. You'll need to ensure that something is running on all of them so they're listening for commands, but that's not too hard.

Comment: well tools like ParallelPython does everything on behalf of user , it makes it diffcult to customise , a single function is being executed in all the client systems , there is no provision that i can manually assgn each job to each client node and as u mentioned that there must be something listening from the clients side , How do i go about building it .

Answer (score 1):

In [Pythomnic](http://www.pythomnic3k.org/) you can have multiple processes on multiple servers exchanging synchronous calls like this:

```
result = pmnc("other_process").module.method(...) # invokes remote method
```

So you can eiher have 3 distinctly named slaves and pick call target manually:

```
pmnc("slave_1").foo.bar() # calls bar() in foo.py on slave_1
```

or have slaves identically named and have the framework pick any available (if they are interchangeable of course)

```
pmnc("slave").foo.bar() # calls bar() in foo.py on any slave
```

Answer (score 1):

check out [RPyc](http://rpyc.wikidot.com/)